# Is there a way to relate the entities in a second repository REST service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a situation where I am trying to define JPA entities that cross two databases. It would have a relationship One to One relationship between the two. In fact there are already JPA Repository REST services across the one. Is there a way to relate the to entities in the second JPA Repository REST service? The two database tables (entities) will be in the same db instance so I can create a db view to make it appear as though it is in the current database and create an entity for that. What is my best approach?

Comment: An option I was looking at is to use a database view and expose a jpa repository in fact I got that set up but when I perform a findall() exposed as REST repository it returns a blank screen with no errors. It's showing in the log that it made the hibernate request but no results. Any help would be appreciative.

Comment: You problem is: You have 2 databases and in REST call you want to mix results from both?